# spring custom converter from basic type other than string not found

Tags: spring, data-binding, converters

I am using Spring 3.1 and i wrote a custom converter

```
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter<Long, Category> {
  @Override
  public Category convert(String id) {
    return BeanProvider.getCategoryDAO().get(id);
  }
}
```

and wired it with mvc in the application context

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
  <property name="converters">
     <set>
       <bean class="converter.CategoryConverter"/>
      </set>
  </property>
</property>
```

Whenever i send the form (that sends a number, namely, the id) then I get a *no matching editors or conversion strategy found* exception.

If i declare the Converter as `Converter<String, Category>` then it miraculously works.

Can anybody point out, why it works only with string and not with long. Is there a way to define the converter in a way, so it works with type `Long` too?